# Flex unable to find definition for type from WCF Service?

Tags: wcf, apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder

I have a WCF Service running SOAP and allowing Flex / Flash to connect to it using basicHttpBinding by using the 'Data' \ 'Import Web Service' option.  Unfortunately when I consume and invoke this service within Flex it throws the following error...

```
Error: Cannot find definition for type 
'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Drawing::Size' at 
mx.rpc.xml::XMLDecoder/decodeType()
```

...when using the following code...

```
// This will return an array of presentations
var service:PresentationAuthoring = new PresentationAuthoring();
var token:AsyncToken = service.getAllPresentationByClientId(
    mClientId , mUserId , mWCFServiceHash );
token.addEventListener( ResultEvent.RESULT, onResult );
token.addEventListener( FaultEvent.FAULT, onFault );
```

This method returns an array of Presentation objects that are retreived by the service.  At the moment there are no DataContracts and I'm allowing the POCO Presentation object to be serialised and punted out by the service that works fine.  However, this class has a readonly property of the type System.Drawing.Size that derived from appropriate height and width properties.  Looking through the generated code, it doesn't register a 'Size' class in the base import schema although it still seems to create a Size class.

An alternative has been to stop the derived property from being serialised using the [XmlIgnore] but that has not worked.

Ideally, I need a way of allowing my Flex application to communicate with my WCF service but it seems to choke on the System.Drawing.Size type and while I could change this, there are other framework types such as Point, Rectangle, etc, etc. that are utilised within the project.  Has anyone else experienced this problem or can suggest an alternative approach to take?

[Please note that the WCF Service functions correctly when a .NET application consumes it.]

Kind regards and thanks in advance - S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer was to box the Size struct with a custom class that worked perfectly although it is somewhat irksome I might have to do this with (potentially) other native drawing structs.  Ho hum.